# Lambda failed to update value?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list and I'm trying to set one `boolean` field **status** to `true` if the **name** field is not **haha**. Below is what I thought it suppose to work but apparently it's not:

```
ObjectList.ForEach(x => !x.name.Equals("haha")).status = true;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await...can be used as a statement
```

May I know which part is wrong in my expression?

Comment: Are you trying to do this with a lambda for any particular reason? It's not the best idiom for this.

Comment: @Gabe: I know it can be easily achieved thru a `foreach` loop. I'm trying to practice myself to understand lambda more

Comment: Just what the error says: `!x.name.Equals("haha")` "is not a statement"; the lambda to `ForEach` is an Action<T>/equiv and has no return value. This error is easy to reproduce *without* LINQ: `var x = true; !x`. Remember to break down a problem.

Comment: @user2864740: You do know that LINQ is not used anywhere in here, right?

Comment: @Gabe Whoops. That is indeed a mistake - I forget `ForEach` is on List, not IEnumerable. The rest stands, replacing "without LINQ" with "without ForEach" or "without a lambda" as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming object list is an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
foreach (var toChange in ObjectList.Where(x => !x.name.Equals("haha"))){
    toChange.Status = true;
}
```

Could also possibly do `ObjectList.Where(x => !x.name.Equals("haha")).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Status = true)`.

Answer (score 2):

That certainly wouldn't do what you wanted it to. `ForEach` doesn't return anything. It executes the delegate you provide against each item in the list, and that's all.

Personally I'd just use `Where` with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var item in ObjectList.Where(x => x.name != "haha"))
{
    item.status = true;
}
```

The exact error itself is because of the `!` part of your expression. The action you execute in `ForEach` is of type `Action<T>`. So you've effectively got:

```
Action<Foo> action = x => !x.name.Equals("haha");
```

That's invalid in the same way that this statement would be invalid:

```
!x.name.Equals("haha"); // Invalid
```

A unary `!` expression isn't a statement expression - you can't use it as a statement on its own. If you just had:

```
x.name.Equals("haha");
```

then it would be valid as a method invocation statement - but still useless.

Answer (score 1):

A `foreach` with a little change in your code will do the trick,

```
       ObjectList.ForEach(obj =>
        {
            if (!obj.name.Equals("haha"))
                obj.status = true;
        });
```

I think you were trying to achieve the same.